# Formula not displaying all specified data

Tags: excel-formula

The following formula is displaying 4 of 5 occurrences. 
    `=COUNTIFS(Referrals!$D$3:$D$325, "DOM", Referrals!$A$3:$A$325, ">="&'Month Source'!M6,$A$3:$A$325,"<="&'Month Source'!M7)`. In other locations it is not displaying the occurrence. 'Month Source'!M6 is the location of the beginning of the month, 'Month Source'!M7 is the end of the month. I checked any data validation columns, & the cell location of the beginning & end of month.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is correct so, on the information publicly available there seems little more to be said, other than the problem seems to be with the data you have not provided. Possibilities include:

- Text that may look like a date but is not
- Extra (in particular, trailing) spaces
- `D0M` rather than `DOM`